# Change the Arrow buttons in Slick slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I want to change the arrows in my slick slider but it does not change. I want the next and previous button as an image. I have tried putting it in a `<style>` but it still not working. Where can I change the arrows setting?

**slick theme css**
    @charset "UTF-8";

```
// Default Variables

$slick-font-path: "./fonts/" !default;
$slick-font-family: "slick" !default;
$slick-loader-path: "./" !default;
$slick-arrow-color: white !default;
$slick-dot-color: black !default;
$slick-dot-color-active: $slick-dot-color !default;
$slick-prev-character: "←" !default;
$slick-next-character: "→" !default;
$slick-dot-character: "•" !default;
$slick-dot-size: 6px !default;
$slick-opacity-default: 0.75 !default;
$slick-opacity-on-hover: 1 !default;
$slick-opacity-not-active: 0.25 !default;

@function slick-image-url($url) {
    @if function-exists(image-url) {
        @return image-url($url);
    }
    @else {
        @return url($slick-loader-path + $url);
    }
}

@function slick-font-url($url) {
    @if function-exists(font-url) {
        @return font-url($url);
    }
    @else {
        @return url($slick-font-path + $url);
    }
}

/* Slider */

.slick-list {
    .slick-loading & {
        background: #fff slick-image-url("ajax-loader.gif") center center no-repeat;
    }
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Icons */
@if $slick-font-family == "slick" {
    @font-face {
        font-family: "slick";
        src: slick-font-url("slick.eot");
        src: slick-font-url("slick.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), slick-font-url("slick.woff") format("woff"), slick-font-url("slick.ttf") format("truetype"), slick-font-url("slick.svg#slick") format("svg");
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
}

/* Arrows */

.slick-prev,
.slick-next {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 30px;
    line-height: 0px;
    font-size: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent;
    color: transparent;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    &:hover, &:focus {
        outline: none;
        background: transparent;
        color: transparent;
        &:before {
            opacity: $slick-opacity-on-hover;
        }
    }
    &.slick-disabled:before {
        opacity: $slick-opacity-not-active;
    }
}

.slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before {
    font-family: $slick-font-family;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1;
    color: $slick-arrow-color;
    opacity: $slick-opacity-default;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.slick-prev {
    left: -25px;
    [dir="rtl"] & {
        left: auto;
        right: -25px;
    }
    &:before {
        content: $slick-prev-character;
        [dir="rtl"] & {
            content: $slick-next-character;
        }
    }
}

.slick-next {
    right: -25px;
    [dir="rtl"] & {
        left: -25px;
        right: auto;
    }
    &:before {
        content: $slick-next-character;
        [dir="rtl"] & {
            content: $slick-prev-character;
        }
    }
}

/* Dots */

.slick-slider {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.slick-dots {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -45px;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    li {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        margin: 0 5px;
        padding: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        button {
            border: 0;
            background: transparent;
            display: block;
            height: 20px;
            width: 20px;
            outline: none;
            line-height: 0px;
            font-size: 0px;
            color: transparent;
            padding: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
            &:hover, &:focus {
                outline: none;
                &:before {
                    opacity: $slick-opacity-on-hover;
                }
            }
            &:before {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                content: $slick-dot-character;
                width: 20px;
                height: 20px;
                font-family: $slick-font-family;
                font-size: $slick-dot-size;
                line-height: 20px;
                text-align: center;
                color: $slick-dot-color;
                opacity: $slick-opacity-not-active;
                -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
                -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
            }
        }
        &.slick-active button:before {
            color: $slick-dot-color-active;
            opacity: $slick-opacity-default;
        }
    }
}
```

**slick css**

```
/* Slider */

.slick-slider {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
    touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
.slick-list {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;

    &:focus {
        outline: none;
    }

    &.dragging {
        cursor: pointer;
        cursor: hand;
    }
}
.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;

    &:before,
    &:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
    }

    &:after {
        clear: both;
    }

    .slick-loading & {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
.slick-slide {
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
    [dir="rtl"] & {
        float: right;
    }
    img {
        display: block;
    }
    &.slick-loading img {
        display: none;
    }

    display: none;

    &.dragging img {
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .slick-initialized & {
        display: block;
    }

    .slick-loading & {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .slick-vertical & {
        display: block;
        height: auto;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
    }
}
```

[preview of the site](https://site-practice-chum.c9.io/Untitled1.html)

Comment: Please can you check the correct answer? Thanks

Answer (score 110):

Slick has a very easy way to customize its buttons through two variables in its own configuration: `prevArrow` and `nextArrow`.

Both types are: string (html | jQuery selector) | object (DOM node | jQuery object), so in your settings slick slider you can set the classes:

```
prevArrow: $('.prev')
nextArrow: $('.next')
```

and add to these elements the styles you want.

For example:

```
//HTML
<div class="slider-box _clearfix">
    <div class="slick-slider">
        <div>
            <img src="img/home_carousel/home_carorusel_1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/home_carousel/home_carorusel_2.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/home_carousel/home_carorusel_3.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/home_carousel/home_carorusel_4.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="paginator-center text-color text-center">
    <h6>VER MAS LANZAMIENTOS</h6>
    <ul>
        <li class="prev"></li>
        <li class="next"></li>
    </ul>
</div>

//JS
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.slick-slider').slick({
      centerMode: true,
      centerPadding: '60px',
      slidesToShow: 3,
      prevArrow: $('.prev'),
      nextArrow: $('.next'),
});

//CSS
.paginator{
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 20px;

  li{
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;

    margin-right: 20px;

    &.prev{
      display: block;
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
      background: url('../img/back.png') no-repeat;
    }

    &.next{
      display: block;
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
      background: url('../img/next.png') no-repeat;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: prevArrow: $ ('.prev')
nextArrow: $ ('.next') . the incorrect dots position got me mixed up for a minute

Comment: Sadly that won't work if there are two or more Slick sliders on one page. If thats the case every one of those custom prev/next buttons will slide all sliders on that page. How is it possible to define only "that" one DOM element asprev/next button for THIS specific slider?

Comment: @Juuro Simple, you would just add a more specific selector instead of just using `'.prev'` alone.

Comment: it works! but be sure you have set 'arrows:true'. With 'arrows:false' wount work

Answer (score 59):

You can easily create your own style of arrow with the `.slick-next:before` and the `.slick-prev:after` pseudo-classes.

Here's an example:

```
.slick-prev:before {
  content: "<";
  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.slick-next:before {
  content: ">";
  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but not quite right.  Should be:  .slick-next:before {
  content: ">";
  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
 }

 .slick-prev:before {
  content: "<";
  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
 }    (using version 1.6.0)

Comment: For me this doesn't work with the "hover" effect. It reverts back to the default size and content. What am I missing?

Comment: I suppose they both must be :before

Answer (score 55):

its very easy. Use the bellow code, Its works for me. Here I have used fontawesome icon but you can use anything as image or any other Icon's code.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.slider').slick({
            autoplay:true,
            arrows: true,
            prevArrow:"<button type='button' class='slick-prev pull-left'><i class='fa fa-angle-left' aria-hidden='true'></i></button>",
            nextArrow:"<button type='button' class='slick-next pull-right'><i class='fa fa-angle-right' aria-hidden='true'></i></button>"
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 36):

This worked for me:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qNbWwK

Hide the default buttons in CSS and use:

```
<!-- In HTML: -->
<p class="left">left</p>
<p class="right">right</p>

/* In the JS file */
$('.slider').slick({
  arrows: false
})

$('.left').click(function(){
  $('.slider').slick('slickPrev');
})

$('.right').click(function(){
  $('.slider').slick('slickNext');
})
```

Comment: Your solution is perfect, thanks. It should be marked as a solution ... anyway thanks a lot

Comment: This works in terms of functionality but people looking at this should be aware that using p tags for an interactive element isn't accessible and means people using a keyboard wont be able to use the arrows.

Buttons should be used instead, they work just as easily and are accessible.

Answer (score 18):

Easy solution:

```
$('.slick-slider').slick({      
    arrows: true,
    prevArrow:"<img class='a-left control-c prev slick-prev' src='YOUR LEFT ARROW IMAGE URL'>",
    nextArrow:"<img class='a-right control-c next slick-next' src='YOUR RIGHT ARROW IMAGE URL'>"
});
```

Image URLs can be local or cdn-type stuff (web icons, etc.).

Example CSS (adjust as needed here, this is just an example of what's possible):

```
.control-c {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

This worked well for me!

Comment: Works well with inline svg too

Comment: this should be the accepted answer! it works perfectly and isn't causing any bugs

Answer (score 11):

If you are using sass you can simply set below mentioned variables,

```
$slick-font-family:FontAwesome;
$slick-prev-character: "\f053";
$slick-next-character: "\f054";
```

These will change the font family used by slick's theme css and also the unicode for prev and next button.

Other sass variables which can be configured are given in [Slick Github page](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/)

Answer (score 10):

You can use FontAwesome "content" values and apply as follow by css. These apply "chevron right/left" icons.

```
.custom-slick .slick-prev:before {
    content: "";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    font-size: 22px;
}
.custom-slick .slick-next:before {
    content: "";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    font-size: 22px;
}
```

Comment: Remember to have imported ccs

@import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css';

----

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

Answer (score 9):

The Best way i Found to do that is this. You can remove my HTML and place yours there.

```
$('.home-banner-slider').slick({
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 3000,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: true,
    prevArrow: '<div class="slick-prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>',
    nextArrow: '<div class="slick-next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>'
});
```

Comment: The buttons wont exist on document ready, they are added once the slick instance has been instantiated. You would want to modify the button html using the `init` event provided by slick.

Comment: You are correct. I made the corrections. This is the permanent solution. But you can edit the html.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It is the built-in solution shown in the dosc on github. ??

Comment: Yeah surely get this upvoted. Worked perfect for me

Answer (score 6):

```
<div class="prev">Prev</div>

<div class="next">Next</div>

$('.your_class').slick({
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 5,
        arrows: true,
        prevArrow: $('.prev'),
        nextArrow: $('.next')
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Add a value for `prevArrow` and `nextArrow` to change the standard arrows.
Example:

```js
    $('.members').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        dots: true,
        arrows: true,
        prevArrow: '<svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M20 40C8.9543 40 -2.7141e-06 31.0457 -1.74846e-06 20C-7.8281e-07 8.9543 8.95431 -2.7141e-06 20 -1.74846e-06C31.0457 -7.8281e-07 40 8.9543 40 20C40 31.0457 31.0457 40 20 40ZM16.1206 13.5198C15.7554 13.1055 15.1632 13.1055 14.798 13.5198L9.58704 19.4308C9.22182 19.8451 9.22182 20.5168 9.58704 20.931L14.798 26.8421C15.1632 27.2563 15.7554 27.2563 16.1206 26.8421C16.4858 26.4278 16.4858 25.7561 16.1206 25.3418L12.4912 21.2248L29.6865 21.2248C30.2388 21.2248 30.6865 20.7771 30.6865 20.2248C30.6865 19.6725 30.2388 19.2248 29.6865 19.2248L12.4138 19.2248L16.1206 15.02C16.4858 14.6057 16.4858 13.934 16.1206 13.5198Z" fill="#7C8B9C"/></svg>',
        nextArrow: '<svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M20 3.49691e-06C31.0457 5.4282e-06 40 8.95431 40 20C40 31.0457 31.0457 40 20 40C8.9543 40 1.56562e-06 31.0457 3.49691e-06 20C5.4282e-06 8.95431 8.95431 1.56562e-06 20 3.49691e-06ZM23.8794 26.4802C24.2446 26.8945 24.8368 26.8945 25.202 26.4802L30.413 20.5692C30.7782 20.1549 30.7782 19.4833 30.413 19.069L25.202 13.1579C24.8368 12.7437 24.2446 12.7437 23.8794 13.1579C23.5142 13.5722 23.5142 14.2439 23.8794 14.6582L27.5088 18.7752L10.3135 18.7752C9.7612 18.7752 9.31348 19.2229 9.31348 19.7752C9.31348 20.3275 9.76119 20.7752 10.3135 20.7752L27.5862 20.7752L23.8794 24.98C23.5142 25.3943 23.5142 26.066 23.8794 26.4802Z" fill="#7C8B9C"/></svg>',
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Content property of pseudo element :before accepts images too. In slick-theme.css change:

```js
// change
$slick-prev-character: "←" !default; 

// to
$slick-prev-character: url('image-prev.png');

// and 
$slick-next-character: "→" !default;

// to 
$slick-next-character: url('image-next.jpg');
```

or directly change the content property on slick-prev:before and slick-next:before

```js
.slick-prev {
    left: -25px;
    [dir="rtl"] & {
        left: auto;
        right: -25px;
    }
    &:before {
        content: url('image-prev.jpg'); // <<<<<<<<
        [dir="rtl"] & {
            content: url('image-next.jpg'); // <<<<<<<<
        }
    }
}

.slick-next {
    right: -25px;
    [dir="rtl"] & {
        left: -25px;
        right: auto;
    }
    &:before {
        content: url('image-next.jpg'); // <<<<<<<<
        [dir="rtl"] & {
            content: url('image-prev.jpg'); // <<<<<<<<
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

here is another example for changing the arrows and using your own arrow-images.

```
.slick-prev:before {
    background-image: url('images/arrow-left.png');
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px;
    content:"";
}
.slick-next:before {
    background-image: url('images/arrow-right.png');
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px;
    content:"";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative solution using javascipt:

```
document.querySelector('.slick-prev').innerHTML = '<img src="path/to/chevron-left-image.svg">'>;
document.querySelector('.slick-next').innerHTML = '<img src="path/to/chevron-right-image.svg">'>;
```

Change the img to text or what ever you require.

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Here is my example of how to change the arrows for Slick Carousel in React to anything you would like.  First you need to set the nextArrow and prevArrow in settings to a function then return a div in that function with whatever icon you would like to use.  For mine I used Font Awesome. Then you will need to add a className in your icon, you will see that in the NextArrow and PrevArrow functions.  Then add the scss code to customize whatever you would like.

JSX Code:

```
function NextArrow(props) {
  const { style, onClick } = props;
  return (
    <div style={{ ...style, display: "block" }} onClick={onClick}>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronRight} size="3x" className="slick-arrow-icon-right" />
    </div>
  );
}

function PrevArrow(props) {
  const { style, onClick } = props;
  return (
    <div style={{ ...style, display: "block" }} onClick={onClick}>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronLeft} size="3x" className="slick-arrow-icon-left" />
    </div>
  );
}

function SlickCarouselArrowChange(props) {
  var settings = {
    className: "slider variable-width",
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    centerMode: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    variableWidth: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    nextArrow: <NextArrow />,
    prevArrow: <PrevArrow />,
  };

  return (
    <div className="slick-slider">
      <Slider {...settings}>
        {props.searchResults.map((image, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <img src={image.urls.small} />{" "}
          </div>
        ))}
      </Slider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

SCSS Code:

```
.slick-arrow-icon-left,
.slick-arrow-icon-right {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  color: black;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  &:hover,
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
    color: black;
    font-size: 40px;
    &::before {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}

.slick-arrow-icon-left {
  left: -50px;
  [dir="rtl"] & {
    left: auto;
    right: -50px;
  }
}

.slick-arrow-icon-right {
  right: -50px;
  [dir="rtl"] & {
    left: -50px;
    right: auto;
  }
}
```

Example Link:

https://slick-carousel-arrow-change.herokuapp.com/

Source Code:

https://github.com/Apocilyptica/slick-carousel-arrow-change

Comment: your links are not working anymore

Answer (score 0):

**For changing the color**

```
.slick-prev:before {
  color: some-color!important;
}
.slick-next:before {
  color: some-color!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your using react-slick you can try this on custom next and prev divs

https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/previous-next-methods

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

If we want to use font awesome library using the css then we can use the below css

```
  .slick-prev:before {
    content: "\f104";
    color: red;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  }

  .slick-next:before {
    content: "\f105";
    color: red;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  }
```

> Font awesome library css must be added in the page.

Answer (score 0):

I was building a Slider Carousel component in React, it worked fine by adding some custom properties for styling arrows:

```
npm install --save react-slick @types/react-slick slick-carousel
```

```
import Slider from 'react-slick';

import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick.css';
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css';

const ImageCorouselSlider = ({ images }: any) => {
  const CustomPrevArrow = (props: any) => (
    <div
      className="slick-arrow slick-prev"
      onClick={props.onClick}
      style={{ color: 'CUSTOM_ARROW_COLOR' }}
    >
      {/* Your custom left arrow icon or content */}
      {/* Example: add SVG */}
    </div>
  );

  const CustomNextArrow = (props: any) => (
    <div
      className="slick-arrow slick-next"
      onClick={props.onClick}
      style={{ color: 'CUSTOM_ARROW_COLOR' }}
    >
      {/* Your custom right arrow icon or content */}
      {/* Example: add SVG */}
    </div>
  );

  const settings = {
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: true,
    prevArrow: <CustomPrevArrow />,
    nextArrow: <CustomNextArrow />,
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Slider {...settings}>
        {images.map((image) => (
          <img
              src={YOUR_IMAGE_SOURCE}
              alt={IMAGE_ALT_VAL}
          />
        ))}
      </Slider>
    </>
  );
};

export default ImageCorouselSlider;
```